# what can be used instead of input type= "password" for password insertion?

Tags: php, html, input

I'm trying to create a basic sign up page using html and php. I've tried to use input type= "password" for my password field; but in that case that does not create any textbox. If I use type =" " I get my desired form.But obviously input remains visible. What will be the simplest way to overcome this problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>On Cash</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
 <!-- Custom Theme files -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/magnific-popup.css">
<!-- Custom Theme files -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="REM KUPUS Responsive web template, Bootstrap Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Andriod Compatible web template, 
Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyErricsson, Motorola web design" 
/>
<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
         <!-- start-smoth-scrolling-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/move-top.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},1000);
                });
            });
        </script>
         <!--start-smoth-scrolling-->
        <!--webfonts-->
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,600italic,700italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <!--//webfonts-->
        <!--start-top-nav-script-->
        <script>
            $(function() {
                var pull        = $('#pull');
                    menu        = $('nav ul');
                    menuHeight  = menu.height();
                $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    menu.slideToggle();
                });
                $(window).resize(function(){
                    var w = $(window).width();
                    if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                        menu.removeAttr('style');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#UserId").keyup(function (e) {

        //removes spaces from username
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));

        var UserId = $(this).val();
        if(UserId.length < 4){$("#user-result").html('');return;}

        if(UserId.length >= 4){
            $("#user-result").html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
            $.post('user_exist.php', {'UserId':UserId}, function(data) {
              $("#user-result").html(data);
            });
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
        <!--//End-top-nav-script-->

    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- start-header-->
            <div id="home" class="header">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="top-header">
                        <div class="logo">
                            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>

                        </div>
                        <!--start-top-nav-->
                         <nav class="top-nav">
                            <ul class="top-nav">
                                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                                <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                                <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                                <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                                    <div class="clearfix"> </div>

                            </ul>
                            <a href="#" id="pull"><img src="images/menu-icon.png" title="menu" /></a>
                        </nav>
                        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                        <lable> </lable>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <!-- Slideshow 4 -->

        <!--/start-two-bites-->

    <!-- /start-services /// user login er part-->
    <div class="service-section">
        <a href="add_new.php"><img src="images/f1.png"/></a>
        <a href="chk_issues.php"><img src="images/f3.png"/></a>
        <a href="chk_transaction.php"><img src="images/f2.png"/></a>



        <form action="insert.php" method="POST">
        <div class="insert">
                <center><br><h3>Fill all the forms for inserting data</h3></br></center>

            <center>
            <br>
                <label for="UserId">Enter Username :
                <input name="UserId" type=" " id="UserId" maxlength="15">
                <span id="user-result"></span>
                </label>
            </br>
            <br>
                <label for="Password">Enter Password:
                <input name="Password" type=" " id="Password" maxlength="15">
                </label>
            </br>
            <br>
                <label for="Confirm Password">Confirm password:
                <input name="Confirm Password" type=" " id="CPassword" maxlength="15">
                </label>
            </br>
            </center>

                <br><center>
                    <input type ="submit" value="save"></center></br>   
        </div>
        </form>

    </div>
<!-- /start-services-->
    <div class="hands-app-section">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="app-hands">
                <div class="col-md-7 hands-text">
                    <h3>Integer vitCelibero ac risus </h3>
                    <h4>Donec odio Quisque volutpat mattis eros Nullam</h4>
                    <span></span>
                    <p>Sed egestas, ante et vulputate volutpat, eros pede semper est, vitae luctus metus libero eu augue. Morbi purus libero, faucibus adipiscing, commodo quis, gravida id, est. Sed lectus. Praesent elementum hendrerit tortor. Sed semper lorem at felis. Vestibulum volutpat, lacus a ultrices sagittis, mi neque </p>
                    <a class="dow-btn" href="#">MORE INFO</a>

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-5 hands-img ">
                    <img src="images/hands.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!--Contents ends here-->
             <div id="contact" class="contact">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h3>contact us</h3>
                        <h4>for more info</h4>
                        <div class="contact-main">
                            <div class="col-md-4 contect-text">
                                <div class="Address">
                                        <h4>Address</h4>
                                        <p>Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio niseuismod in</p>
                                        <span>Morbi in sem quis dui placerat ornare. Pellentesque odio niseuismod in</span>
                                            <ul class="links">
                                            <li><a href="mailto:info@example.com">info@sitename.com</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="mailto:info@example.com">sales@sitename.com</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="mailto:info@example.com">contact@sitename.com</a></li>
                                        </ul>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8 contect-text">     
                                    <form method="post" action="#">
                                                <li>
                                                    <input type="text" class="text" value="Name" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Name';}" ><a href="#" class=" icon user"></a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <input type="password" value="Password" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Password';}"><a href="#" class=" icon lock"></a>
                                                </li>

                                                    <div class="clear"> </div>
                                                <li class="message-box">
                                                    <textarea value="Message" onfocus="this.value = '';" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Message ';}">Message</textarea><a href="#" class=" icon pen"></a>
                                                </li>   
                                               <div class="submit"> 
                                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit " />
                                              </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>  
                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--start-footer-->

        <!--/start-footer-->
                <div class="footer">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="copy-right">
                                    <p>&copy; 2014  All Rights  Reserved | Template by &nbsp;<a href="http://w3layouts.com">W3Layouts</a></p>
                            </div>  
                        </div>  
                        <div class="clearfix"> </div>                           
                    </div>
                    <!-- //End-footer-->
                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(document).ready(function() {
                                        /*
                                        var defaults = {
                                            containerID: 'toTop', // fading element id
                                            containerHoverID: 'toTopHover', // fading element hover id
                                            scrollSpeed: 1200,
                                            easingType: 'linear' 
                                        };
                                        */

                                        $().UItoTop({ easingType: 'easeOutQuart' });

                                    });
                                </script>
                    <a href="#" id="toTop" style="display: block;"> <span id="toTopHover" style="opacity: 1;"> </span></a>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your entire HTML document. The first line should be `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: And maybe add the CSS: If the box does not render, css might be the issue.

Comment: "password" *is* the correct type. use it. then fix the actual problem. if only trying to treat the symptoms it'll end as a gob of goo.

Comment: review your JS or CSS, there's a chance that it's not render or display it off, try to inspect element if your input is still there.

Comment: I tried to use "password" but my layout changes 
http://imagebin.ca/v/1vOeQNzX21Hf

Comment: so fix *that* problem - don't make up a new one. use the developer inspector tools to see what CSS is (or isn't) applied.

Comment: I'm using a template file thus i'm not very sure which css might be required. I'm trying again. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: @user232803 can you upload the html you used with the image?

Comment: Here it is http://pastebin.com/KqD7QXYK

Comment: You're going to have a hard time with `name="Confirm Password" type=" "`

Comment: @user232803 that is still the old code

Comment: I'm a beginner :( All i'm doing to use trial and error process. I'm not good with html at all I'll change/look after that once password type works properly@Fred-ii-

Comment: just paste the whole style.css please so we could tell if there is something wrong.

Comment: Style.css http://pastebin.com/PhabF0N9

Comment: @user232803 Than you haven't changed your code with my example, make sure you changes are submit, maybe you use ftp, please check if this is working.

Comment: can you remove from _style.css_ `, input[type="password"]` **line 1172** then let see if it return the same.

Comment: It worked! I had to use both solution provided by perry and yamidemichaos. Thanks a lot!

Comment: no problem, gladly to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for :

```
type="password"
```

Example for password input field:

```
<input type="password" name="password">
```

Also you use the for with your label, the things is the for looks for the id and not the name. Also you better use name without a whitespace this makes is easier for yourself.

Example for how your password piece will look like:

```
<br>
            <label for="password-new">Enter Password:
            <input name="passwordnew" type="password" id="password-new" maxlength="15">
            </label>
        </br>
        <br>
            <label for="confirm-password">Confirm password:
            <input name="confirmpassword" type="password" id="confirm-password" maxlength="15">
            </label>
        </br>
```

Comment: that does not work with provided html file.. I've already tried using this. It does not show empty white textbox if I use this
http://imagebin.ca/v/1vOeQNzX21Hf

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
    <div class="insert">
            <center><br><h3>Fill all the forms for inserting data</h3></br></center>

        <center>
        <br>
            <label for="UserId">Enter Username :
            <input name="UserId" type=" " id="UserId" maxlength="15">
            <span id="user-result"></span>
            </label>
        </br>
        <br>
            <label for="Password">Enter Password:
            <input name="Password" type="password" id="Password" maxlength="15">
            </label>
        </br>
        <br>
            <label for="Confirm Password">Confirm password:
            <input name="Confirm Password" type="password" id="CPassword" maxlength="15">
            </label>
        </br>
        </center>

            <br><center>
                <input type ="submit" value="save"></center></br>   
    </div>
    </form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xr9mhn06/1/

Comment: You know that `type=" "` keep the **confirm password** visible and it is not advisable to use **empty value** type. I think the problem is in the doc type or in the rendering.

Comment: I didn't even look at the confirm password @yamidemichaos. Thanks. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I already did try to use input type "password" but it gives me this layout
http://imagebin.ca/v/1vOeQNzX21Hf

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmmmm changing type to "password" works for me.... And the only other way I can think of would be using java script or java query and although it doesn't take much work it shouldn't be needed.

Have you tried clearing your cache? what browser are you using? (it works fine in chrome)

PS: Your indentations and formatting are a little unorthadox and you don't need to end break tags, just br is enough.

I just made this a html file and ran it in chrome and it worked perfectly.

```
<form action="insert.php" method="POST">
<div class="insert">
    <center><h3>Fill all the forms for inserting data</h3></center>
        <center>
            <br>
            <label for="UserId">Enter Username :
                <input name="UserId" type=" " id="UserId" maxlength="15">
                <span id="user-result"></span>
            </label>
            <br>
            <label for="Password">Enter Password:
                <input name="Password" type="password" id="Password" maxlength="15">
            </label>
            <br>
            <label for="Confirm Password">Confirm password:
                <input name="Confirm Password" type="password" id="CPassword" maxlength="15">
            </label>
            <br>
        </center>
        <center><input type ="submit" value="save"></center>   
    </div>
</form>
```

EDIT: Given the image in one of the comments on another answer. (that I cannot comment on because my rep isn't high enough)

Would the stylesheet you are using not have type="password' defined? or override it for some reason?

Comment: I've inspect the template again. It has input type= "password" defined. Do not know why it's not working with custom defined label

Comment: Can you show us what the template has for input type="password" and also type=" " (or type="text") and compare them.